# Flexbox, float or display table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

> **Update** Please note [kukkuz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013995/2008111) answer is a nice hack but it is **NOT working 100%** if the first box becomes more content see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1yfwcto/1) then the center box starts moving to the right

What I need is something like this:

[image]

Where:

1. First box `"Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet"` has always to be left positioned
2. Second box `"center content"` has always to be centered
3. Third box `"float left after center"` has to be right after the center box
4. All of those boxes will have variable content length so it can be less content then shown in picture or much more. **For every single of those 3 tomato colored boxes**

This is what I have

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="flex-item">center content</div>
  <div class="flex-item">float left after center</div>
</div>
```

Now not sure how to achieve the desired result. Is `flex-box` the right way to go or should I use `display-table`? I'm 97% sure it doesn't work with floating. How can I achieve the desired result?

> **Update from question in comments**
>
> **Q:** suppose the first box has large content such that the second box will overlap the first, if it is at the center... how do you look to
> handle that?
>
> **A:** probably with overflow hidden and z-index. It will be a toolbar underneath a gallery. Left box will describe something of the image,
> middle box is the gallery navigation, and the right box will display
> some "helper" text. so the gallery navigation is the most important
> which must always be visible (and centered)

Comment: Second box `center content` isn't centered in your image: it's the combination of #2 + #3 that is centered in the remaining space left by #1 (e.g. as much lightblue background visible on left of #2 then on right of #3). Is it what you're trying to achieve or do you want #2 really "centered" (as far from the left side of #1 than from the right side of the rightmost lightblue background)?

Comment: @FelipeAls you're right! it should be centered over the entire space. I'll update the picture, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: True centering of #2 can only be achieved by removing #1 with [absolute positioning](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/VmxxRz?editors=0100#) I guess (as far as their widths are unknown) and well it doesn't play nicely with large blocks

Comment: @FelipeAls in your example the centered box will also not be centered if the last box changes content. So might be better to use something like display table or at least not using flex-box for this approach?

Comment: It's not even centered (#2+#3 are), forget it :/

Comment: You say they can be any length, but it's unclear what should happen if they start to overlap?

Comment: Are you open to a solution that uses javascript?

Comment: @aw04 please look at [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013904/flexbox-float-or-display-table#comment69236898_41013995) just below this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013904/flexbox-float-or-display-table#comment69236708_41013995). **JS is not an option.** I will also update the question providing this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a solution. But I needed an auxiliar wrapper for the side elements.

You cant set a minimum width (arbitrary) on the side containers. I have set this to 10px, just to give the idea.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.side {
  flex: 10px 1 0;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
.center {
  flex: auto 0 0;
  background: tomato;
}
.side div {
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item side">
    <div>Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item center">center content</div>
  <div class="flex-item side">
    <div>float left after center</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! this looks very good! this is the best answer so far! tested some different contents and seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5o86rye7/

Answer (score 10):

I certainly miss `justify-self` but you can try a hack: add `margin-right: auto` to the first and third `flex-item`s - see demo below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.auto {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item auto">Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="flex-item">center content</div>
  <div class="flex-item auto">float left after center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damm it's not really working if the first box becomes more content see here: https://jsfiddle.net/g1yfwcto/1/ then the center box starts moving to the right and does not remain centered if in the fiddle you remove/add the `sadfasfasfdasfd` you will see the center box moving. gets even worse if last box has less content: https://jsfiddle.net/g1yfwcto/2/

Comment: you are right, it doesn't work if there is content width nears the half of screen width... maybe that is why I mentioned about being a *hack*...

Comment: So I might have to use `display table` to achieve the result? or will it be possible with `display flex`?

Comment: one question : suppose the fist box has large content such that the second box will overlap the first, if it is at the center... how do you look to handle that?

Comment: probably with overflow hidden and z-index. It will be a toolbar underneath a gallery. Left box will describe something of the image, middle box is the gallery navigation, and the right box will display some "helper" text. so the gallery navigation is the most important which must always be visible (and centered)

Comment: I feel like the only way to reliable make this work is with `max-width` and `height: auto;`. This will make sure that your centered content is always centered and your left content never takes up more width than it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if using `display-table` might be the better solution for my problem. It seems to look good with all different content lengths. Not sure how the

```
max-width: 10px;
```

works on the `.table-cell` but seems to do the job..

```css
.display-table {
  display: table;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: tomato;
  max-width: 10px;
}

.table-cell:first-child,
.table-cell:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="table-cell">center content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">float left after center</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="display-table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="table-cell">center content center content center content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">float left after center</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="display-table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat asperiores aliquid rerum optio perferendis aut debitis delectus. Rerum, facilis pariatur debitis libero accusantium numquam expedita ratione aliquid quae temporibus excepturi! ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="table-cell">center content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">float left after center</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="display-table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat asperiores aliquid rerum optio perferendis aut debitis delectus. Rerum, facilis pariatur debitis libero accusantium numquam expedita ratione aliquid quae temporibus excepturi! ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="table-cell">center</div>
    <div class="table-cell">float left after center float left after center periores aliquid rerum optio perferendis aut debitis delectus. Rerum, facilis pariatur debitis libero accusantium numquam expedita ratione aliquid quae temporibus excepturi! ipsumd dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: [Here is link to fiddle if someone is interested in resizing or editing](https://jsfiddle.net/j2mpzrsh/1/)

Comment: good to know you found the required answer +1... nice one with tables... :)

Comment: @kukkuz thanks for looking back! well it's still not 100% still missing how to set the max-width properly for the centered box. as it should just use the desired width ... (with no borders and colors I think it does the job though and looks ok)

Comment: This solution looks quite different to what you're asking in the question. It looks like you are just dividing the container in 3 equal parts and then aligning the text - notice that the whole container has a background color of tomato (as apposed to the image in the question)

Comment: @Danield correct, align-left twice and centered the one in the middle. it does the job but is not the solution I'm really looking for. Causing other shitty issues.. But trying to show that I'm after a solution and open minded. If you have a better one, please share, Should be real easy shouldn't it?

Comment: I just posted a solution - but you should know that this is not a trivial layout that you're after

Answer (score 2):

I'm don't think it is possible with CSS alone to suit all your conditions and without adding a wrapper div - using any method.

You can get pretty close using a combination of `position:absolute` and `margin-left` except that the middle element won't be exactly in the centre.

```css
.container {
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.item1, .item2, .item3 {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.item1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  z-index: 0;
}
.item2 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  //transform: translateX(-50%); /* will center, but then no way to pull item3 back */
  z-index:1;
}
.item3 {
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"> Lorem ipsumd dolor heth ehe h </div>
  <div class="item2">center content</div>
  <div class="item3">float left after center</div>
</div>

position the first item with a lower z-index - incase the first item is really long

<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"> Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet fgfdg theth ehe h Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet fgfdg theth ehe h </div>
  <div class="item2">center content</div>
  <div class="item3">float left after center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad but if center box has less content it is not centered, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8fv1tzea/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS

```
 .flex-item:nth-of-type(1),.flex-item:nth-of-type(3)
    {
      margin-right:auto;
    }
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
.flex-item:nth-of-type(1),.flex-item:nth-of-type(3)
{
  margin-right:auto;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="flex-item">center content</div>
  <div class="flex-item">float left after center</div>
</div>
```